# mysql search engine with no result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to build a search engine but I'm having a problem using this query:

```
SELECT mydb.*, ((keywords LIKE '%pedals%')+(keywords LIKE '%noword%')) AS best_match 
FROM mydb 
WHERE valid = 1 AND (keywords LIKE '%pedals%') AND (keywords LIKE '%noword%') 
ORDER BY best_match DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

but if I digit two keyword witch only one keyword is included in my db (example: "pedals" and "noword") the query will return no result, instead should return "bike".

[query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eelGC.png) -
[mydb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcxh3.png)

Thanks

Comment: Strongly suggest you save yourself a world of pain and see normalisation

Comment: A little confused.  Are you looking for `or` instead of `and`? `keywords LIKE '%pedals%' OR keywords LIKE '%noword%'`

Answer (score 0):

With that current table design you would need conditions such as these to calculate a "best match"

```
SELECT mydb.id, mydb.title, mydb.description, mydb.keywords
    , case when keywords LIKE '%pedals%' then 1 else 0 end
    + case when keywords LIKE '%noword%' then 1 else 0 end
as best_match 
FROM mydb 
WHERE valid = 1 AND (keywords LIKE '%pedals%') OR (keywords LIKE '%noword%') 
ORDER BY best_match DESC
```